# How to use interface block for type overloading

Tags: inheritance, interface, fortran, overloading, fortran2003

I’ve written a Fortran code to read different text files. Each text file has its own type that defines the reading procedure that inherits from a abstract type which defines general operations:

```
module FileImporter_class
implicit none
private
type, abstract, public :: FileImporter
.
.
contains
    procedure, public :: ProcessFile
.
.
end type FileImporter
contains
.
.
subroutine ProcessFile(self,FileName)
implicit none
    ! Declaring Part
    class(FileImporter) :: self
    character(len=*) :: FileName

    ! Executing Part
    call self%SetFileName(FileName)
    call self%LoadFileInMemory
    call self%ParseFile
end subroutine ProcessFile
end module FileImporter_class
```

Here's the inheriting class:

```
module optParser_class
use FileImporter_class
implicit none
type, public, extends(FileImporter) :: optParser
.
. 
contains
    procedure, public :: ParseFile
end type optParser
interface optParser
    procedure ProcessFile
end interface
contains
.
.
end module optParser_class
```

My question is about the interface block. I want to invoke the procedure `ProcessFile` by simply calling the type, so `call optParser('inputfile.txt')`. This variant shown gives an compiling error (ProcessFile not an function nor subroutine). I could solve this by putting a `ProcessFile` function in the `optParser_class` module, but then I would have to do this for every inheriting class, which I naturally want to avoid. Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not allowed by Fortran standards to put a subroutine into an interface blocks which overloads a type name.

Only functions can be put into such interfaces and they are then typically used to return objects of that type (constructors or initializers).

Instead you should just call it as a type-bound procedure, because `optParser` inherits it from `FileImporter` from

```
 call variable_of_optParser_type%ProcessFile('inputfile.txt')
```

There are no Python-like classmethods which can be called without an instance in Fortran. Notice `ProcessFile` has the `self` argument, so it **has to** receive some object instance.

BTW, I recommend you to make one convention, whether your type start with a small or capital letter and stick to it to avoid confusion.

Comment: thank you very much. I'm still new to OOP in Fortran, so i don't know what is applicable and/or allowed and what not.